# Имена объектов только на одном языке

Tags: google-maps-api, javascript

Перекопал верь API справочник, так и не нашел как убрать перевод объекта на карте в местном языке. Вообще кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким, и в какую сторону смотреть?

[image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [ответ](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=ru&answer=63471) на ваш вопрос. API тут бесполезно.